# Issue with Fortify SCA scanning multiple GitHub repositories at the same time

Tags: static-analysis, fortify

I'm running into an issue where if I specify a folder path containing multiple GitHub repos for Fortify SCA (23.1) to scan, it'll run the analysis slowly but never generate an FPR file at the end of the scan. Do I have to scan these repos individually and concatenate the results together?

It seems to get stuck forever on "Rendering the Results..." and when I check the System Manager, about half my available memory (46Gb) is being taken up by the SourceAnalyzer. The combined repos is about 1Gb in size.

[image]